# A question on submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   a & b & c  \\
   d & e & f  \\
   g & h & i  \\
\end{array}} \right)$  is normal  and  unitary similar with $D = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{\lambda _1}} & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & {{\lambda _2}} & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & {{\lambda _3}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)$.

Now suppose $B = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   a & b  \\
   d & e  \\
\end{array}} \right)$ be positive semidefinite ,can we prove that $B$ is unitary similar with ${D^*} = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   {{\lambda _1}} & 0  \\
   0 & {{\lambda _1}}  \\
\end{array}} \right)$?

Comment: Your $B$ isn't even a submatrix of $A$, so there seems to be no reason why it would have any particular relation to it. For example consider $I_{3\times 3}$, then $B=({}^1_0\;{}^0_0)$, which certainly isn't similar to your $D^*$, even if you intended for the second diagonal element of $D^*$ to be $\lambda_2$ rather than $\lambda 1$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm - I'm sorry, I edited this post.

Comment: Even with the new $B$, consider $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$ with eigenvalues $1$, $1$, and $-1$. Then your $B$ is positive semidefinite but has eigenvalues $1$ and $0$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm  - Thanks.